# ReportExport duplicates a row when exporting to Excel (not to other formats)

Tags: excel, reporting-services, duplicates

I am using tablix and group my entries by one of the properties. I have some trouble with SSRS when exporting my report to Excel. The very first row of each group is added to the end of its group.
This only(!) happens when exporting the report to Excel, exporting to any other format will leave my table the way it should be:

[image: SO20355546 question example]

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I see that this is an old question but I have the same problem and I've been able to solve it just changing the Visibility property of the different tablix components.

In my case I have this.

Row Visibility: "Hide" and also set "Can be toogle by" with the parent group.

Group Visibility: "Show".

Each textbox of the detail row Visibility: "Show".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is not removing dupes for you in the grouping that repeat.  Are you doing a regular grouping with property or a function?  There are two solutions for this:

1. Ensure your dataset is having distinct values (even if you think you are certain).  If this is standard 'select' statement to a SQL Server just add Select 'Distinct' and your values.
2. I would try maybe making the properties in the table that are in the lowest level, shown as '[Details]' generally in the design section under 'Row Groups'.  Change the properties to be something like:

   [Max(propertyb)] and [Max(propertyc)]

   This is not needed generally as the grouping should be taking care of this.  But in cases where it is not it is an extra level of logic may fix the issue.  You also need to be aware depending on your grouping logic that if it is not grouping properly you may get the same result for that many rows.   This would not be as advised as it is more of a hack to get what you want, not an elegant solution.

Comment: Hey django, thank you for your answer!
your solution was not quite what I was looking for, but I suppose that my question was asked rather poorly.
Luckily by now I have found a solution:
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/508823/

Answer (score 0):

hi to solve this issue follow the steps

1. in the report design right click on the first cell of the group that showing
   duplicate, click **Add Group>Parent Group>check the add group header** checkbox
2. then a **new column and an empty row will created** in the design in that column
   there is one heading  and a value  you need to clear them
3. for to hide the newly added column  in the column for every cell right click
   and set visibility as hide then shrink the column to width as zero we can
   manually drag and shrink that
4. finally for that newly added row you can select allover the row and set row
   visibility as hide

Hope this will fix this issue

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).